# How to set new mesh object on line + three js

Tags: 3d, three.js, mesh

I have one line between 2 vector.

I am trying to add the new sprite mesh on line. and new mesh (sprite) setting position to center of the line.
by below code

```
        let midLoc = {
            x: ((fromLoc.x + toLoc.x) / 2),
            y: ((fromLoc.y + toLoc.y) / 2),
            z: ((fromLoc.z + toLoc.z) / 2)
        };

        let midOffset = new THREE.Vector3(midLoc.x, midLoc.y, midLoc.z);

        this.setPosition(midOffset.x, midOffset.y + 20, midOffset.z);
```

new mesh on center location:-

[new mesh on center location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68Huk.png) {Please click this link for image as not able to paste image as don't have reputation more than 10 :P }

But I want to set the new mesh position to near to from location or to location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option, you can do it this way:

Green - start, Blue - end, Red - middle.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 5, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

var points = [
  new THREE.Vector3(-5, 1, 2), //start
  new THREE.Vector3(4, 3, -1)  //end
]

var lineGeom = new THREE.Geometry();
lineGeom.vertices = points;
var line = new THREE.Line(lineGeom, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: "yellow"
}));
scene.add(line);

var midPoint = new THREE.Vector3().addVectors(points[0], points[1]).multiplyScalar(0.5);

var midMarker = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.125, 4, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "red"
}));
midMarker.position.copy(midPoint);
scene.add(midMarker);

var directionFrom = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(points[1], points[0]).normalize();
var directionTo = directionFrom.clone().negate();

var fromMarker = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25, 4, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "green"
}));
fromMarker.position.copy(points[0]).add(directionFrom);
scene.add(fromMarker);

var toMarker = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25, 4, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "blue"
}));
toMarker.position.copy(points[1]).add(directionTo);
scene.add(toMarker);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/91/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot for quick and correct reply. **It works !** I was dying to calculate the points in line direction. Wonderful Logic.